# Get constructor declaration from ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax with Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to use Roslyn to take an Object Creation Expressions in a C# source file and add name all parameters (so from `new SomeObject("hello")` to `new SomeObject(text: "hello")`.

I've got the ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax from the SyntaxTree as well as a SemanticModel for the solution. I'm trying to use `GetSymbol/TypeInfo` for the `ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax`'s type, but I can't seem to use that to get the the parameter names.

Basically what I'm trying to get is this:

[image]

Specifically the parameters of `Something.Something`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ask the `SemanticModel` for the `SymbolInfo` for the node you're visiting / rewriting. The symbol it returns *should* always be an `IMethodSymbol` with a property `Parameters` containing all parameters of the constructor.

Out of curiosity I've written a `SyntaxRewriter` that does exactly what you want. It of course hasn't been thoroughly tested, there will be cases I've missed (or just omitted, like already named parameters).

```
public class NameAllParametersRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    private readonly SemanticModel _semanticModel;

    public NameAllParametersRewriter(Document document)
    {
        _semanticModel = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
    }

    public override SyntaxNode VisitObjectCreationExpression(
        ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax node)
    {
        var baseResult = (ObjectCreationExpressionSyntax)
            base.VisitObjectCreationExpression(node);

        var ctorSymbol = _semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
        if (ctorSymbol == null)
            return baseResult;

        var newArgumentListArguments = new SeparatedSyntaxList<ArgumentSyntax>();
        for (int i = 0; i < baseResult.ArgumentList.Arguments.Count; i++)
        {
            var oldArgumentSyntax = baseResult.ArgumentList.Arguments[i];
            var parameterName = ctorSymbol.Parameters[i].Name;

            var identifierSyntax = SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(parameterName);
            var nameColonSyntax = SyntaxFactory
                .NameColon(identifierSyntax)
                .WithTrailingTrivia(SyntaxFactory.Whitespace(" "));

            var newArgumentSyntax = SyntaxFactory.Argument(
                nameColonSyntax, 
                oldArgumentSyntax.RefOrOutKeyword, 
                oldArgumentSyntax.Expression);

            newArgumentListArguments = newArgumentListArguments.Add(newArgumentSyntax);
        }

        return baseResult
            .WithArgumentList(baseResult.ArgumentList
                .WithArguments(newArgumentListArguments));
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, Roslyn is turning out to be a lot more powerful than I expected :D I can't test this right now, but it looks like it will work. Thanks!